# Is it possible to burn a DVD out of the Lion app store install?

Tags: macos, install, dvd-burning

Is it possible to burn a DVD out of the Lion app store install?

Comment: You can also throw it on a bootable USB key: http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/08/make-a-bootable-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-installer-from-a-usb-flash-drive/

Comment: Exactly. This is much faster than using a DVD.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes!

After you purchase and download Lion from the App Store, the "Install" screen will appear:

[image: Mac OS X Lion Install Screen]

Before you click **Continue**, open your **Applications** folder and look for the icon labelled **Install Mac OS X Lion**:

[image: Applications Folder Screen]

If you missed this chance (and the App is deleted from your system), you can always **re-download** the package using the **App Store** app. Even if it shows Lion Installed, you can hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key pressed, then press the button to re-download the Lion installer app.

Right-click (or Ctrl+Click) on this and choose **Show Package Contents**. Navigate to **Contents** > **SharedSupport** and look for **InstallESD.dmg**.

[image: Package contents of the Install Mac OS X Lion package]

Use Disk Utility (in the Utilities folder inside the Applications folder) to burn InstallESD.dmg to a DVD. Drag the InstallESD.dmg file to the Disk Utility window, select it, then choose **Burn...** from the Images menu.

A dialog appears allowing you to burn it to a DVD. The name of the DVD doesn't really matter, but I named mine **Mac OS X Lion**.

[image]

Comment: Nice tutorial Joel!

Comment: I have a question. Should I accept Joel's answer because it's "nicer", or should I accept palanijara because it's the first correct answer

Comment: Accept the one that solved your problem ;-) I wrote mine because palanijara's depends on an outside link. We generally don't like answers that are just a URL here because essentially you've made a page that doesn't actually answer a question for anyone else who lands there from google, it's just a resting-stop on the way to the real answer.

Comment: How big is it.  What size USB key would I need for this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes http://lifehacker.com/5812997/burn-the-mac-app-store-version-of-os-x-lion-to-a-dvd

Comment: Please see http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/485/are-answers-that-just-contain-a-link-acceptable

Comment: Thanks for the heads up koiyu. I'll post the excerpt next time with the link. Joel already posted detailed answer after my post.

Comment: @koiyu, Well in fairness, it's not a link only answer, he answers the question with a simple yes and then provides a link. Maybe the answer could use more detail, but it's not a straight link only answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy **Install Mac OS X Lion**.app — in its entirety — to a DVD that is not bootable.

A widely promoted hack involves using *only a part* of the .app for 10.7 (Build 11A511) to create a DVD (or USB flash drive, or external hard disk partition) that is bootable. Bootable media produced in this way from this source may be good for *some* uses but please, [proceed with caution: other uses may leave a system unusable](http://identi.ca/conversation/76905136#notice-79505996).

Be aware of the known risks, and unknowns, associated with straying from what is recommended by Apple.

Comment: [Discussion in Ask Different Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/conversation/home-produced-bootable-media-for-lion-known-risks-and-unknowns-around-10-7-buil)

Comment: What are the risks? You are being very ominous here but I've followed your links and I don't understand what you think might happen.

Comment: benzado, recently discussed in Ask Different Chat: [home-produced bootable media for Lion: known risks and unknowns around 10.7 (Build 11A511)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/conversation/home-produced-bootable-media-for-lion-known-risks-and-unknowns-around-10-7-buil)

Comment: Can you summarize that? I have a hard time following the chat dialogue. It seems like there is some FileVault-related issue but that's it?

Comment: benzado, the answers may be multiple and complex (more than I alone can answer). I think it would make a good question, if you would like to ask it. Something like 'What risks surround nonstandard uses of .dmg files for 10.7 (Build 11A511)?' …

Comment: PS sorry for the repeated link. Pale blue text on white background was overlooked.