# How can I burn an OS X Lion install DVD once the installer has been auto-deleted?

Tags: install, mac-appstore, macos

I've just installed OS X Lion on my iMac, and I want to make an installation DVD, so that I can reinstall without having to first install Snow Leopard.

The way to create the DVD is answered [elsewhere](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17761/is-it-possible-to-burn-a-dvd-out-of-the-lion-app-store-install), but it seems that the installer gets [auto deleted](http://osxdaily.com/2011/06/08/create-burn-bootable-mac-os-x-lion-install-disc/) after the installation of Lion completes.

It looks like I'll have to re-download the 4Gb Lion installer again, but when I try to download it again via the App store, I'm told a newer version already exists, and I'll have to move it to the trash first.

I've double checked, and there isn't another version of the installer present.

How can I now create the install disk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can re-download Lion even though it has already been installed by holding down the <kbd>option</kbd> key before clicking **Purchased**.

Do not release the key until after the option to **Install** appears alongside **OS X Lion**.

The workaround may be more reliable if something *other* than Purchased is in foreground *before* alt/option-clicking Purchased.

Burn the installer to disc, then delete it when you're done with it.

Comment: Holding down option didn't work for me...any other ideas?

Comment: @Steve: hold Option key while clicking 'Purchased' tab.