# Is it possible to run Mountain Lion on older hardware by using a virtualization solution?

Tags: mac, macos, virtualization

I'm wondering if anyone has gotten Mountain Lion to run on any hardware in virtualization ([VMware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html), [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com), [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) or other...). If so, it would be interesting to know how well (if at all) attempting to run the 10.8 OS on Mac hardware that normally wouldn't allow an installation of the OS.

Has anyone taken a Mountain Lion VM and run it on older hardware?

Comment: Would you be interested in the result of running 10.8 in a VirtualBoxVM on a 2009 Mac where the physical machine *is* capable of 10.8? MacBookPro5,2 here with 8 GB memory. Some users might view this class of machine as old.

Comment: Yes - ideally results for more old hardware is sought, but any information about what mix of VM and OS work - even on a new platform would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

## 10.7.x or 10.8 (Build 12A269) in VirtualBox

There's an [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58612/8546) under [How can I install Mac OS X Lion in VirtualBox, or any other type of virtual machine?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/17945/8546).

I guess, a `.vdi` of Mountain Lion produced in that way will be usable with at least some Macs that might not otherwise run the OS.

### Example

Physical machine:

- MacBookPro5,2 with 8 GB memory
- VirtualBox 4.2.0 Beta 1.

In the VirtualBoxVM:

- Build 12A269 of OS X 10.8
- without FileVault 2
- with Core Storage encryption of something other than the startup volume
- [dynamic_pager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/dynamic_pager.8.html) disabled:

[image: a screenshot of OS X 10.8 in VirtualBox with dynamic_pager disabled]

Alongside an [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/24508/8546) to [Why would I disable swap file in Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/24502/8546), note that **without** swap files, Activity Monitor measures both:

- virtual memory size
- page ins.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now that I've jumped into trying Virtual Box, I'll give this a shot and let you know how things work.