# Fusion-drive on OS 10.7

Tags: fusion-drive

I have a new iMac, but I need to revert back to OS10.7 for software compatibility issues at work. Will the fusion-drive function properly?

Comment: I don't know, but if you get it to work, you shouldn't use the Disk Utility version included in OS X 10.7 (from http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5446):`The version of Disk Utility that comes with Fusion Drive is unique. Earlier versions of Disk Utility can't be used with a Fusion Drive.` (The latest version of Lion is 10.7.5, released Oct 3rd 2012. Fusion Drive was introduced later.)

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is not only the Fusion drive but the new iMac hardware as a whole. Older OS X versions usually do not work on hardware released after the release date of the respective OS X due to missing drivers etc.

Alternatively you could try to install [10.7 in a virtual machine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17945/how-can-i-install-mac-os-x-lion-in-virtualbox-or-any-other-type-of-virtual-mach).