# How to move Lion installer to another Mac?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I installed Lion on my MacBook Pro.  Worked great.

Now I want to install it on my iMac, I don't want to re-download it from the App Store because it's a 3.5GB download and I have to pay for all my bandwidth (yes, I'm Canadian).

Is the installer executable on my MacBook Pro somewhere?  If so, where is it and can I just copy it to the iMac and run it?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the installer package contains the source files for the installation and this package is deleted once installation has completed.

If you still have the installer in Applications, right-click on it and Show Package Contents then browse to the /Contents/SharedSupport/ folder and look for the InstallESD.dmg disk image. This image can be burnt to a dvd saving future downloads but I am afraid you are going to have to download it again.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the installer is removed after a successful installation of Lion, so you'll probably need to download it again.

Answer (score 1):

As described here, you can save a copy prior to install: http://www.cultofmac.com/save-your-bandwidth-prevent-os-x-lion-installer-from-self-destructing/105470

Answer (score 1):

From another question....

[Is it possible to burn a DVD out of the Lion app store install?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17761/is-it-possible-to-burn-a-dvd-out-of-the-lion-app-store-install)

Joel has a nice set of instructions on how to do this.