# Is it possible to do a "clean" install of Lion?

Tags: macos, install

Is it possible to take a Lion install burned by the method outlined in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17761/) and preform a clean install with it?

I just want to make sure that if I buy Lion from the App Store in the near future that when the mood strikes me I will be able to reformat and install Lion without some previous install of Snow Leopard.

Comment: leopard or lion?

Comment: @bckbck, lion, sorry I got distract while writing the question, just fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It is bootable, and will be able to do a complete clean install (with you having to format the hard disk first).

Also, if you have installed Lion already, you would be able to do a reinstall by holding <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> on bootup and selecting Recovery HD. Wait for it to load, and you will be able to see an option for reinstalling.

Comment: But note that the Recovery HD reinstall will download Lion from Apple again -- the recovery partition isn't big enough to contain a complete install of Lion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I figured as much but just wanted to sure.

Comment: Just to note - I did a clean install on my mid-2007 Macbook and it worked perfectly. There was one issue - it inexplicably failed mid-install and restarted to a circle with a slash through it. Subsequent installation attempts failed, until I reset the PRAM.

Comment: Will doing a re-install using the Recovery HD perform a *clean* install (IE: throw away user files + settings)? If not, what is the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Apple have published a very nice how to install lion that goes over the steps to install it internally as well as on a second drive.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718